# Need to insert a single data in the database

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm having a problem to insert a single data from my database

Example: I have two data's which is the question1 with ID:1 and question2: with ID:2. Those 2 questions does have different button. The problem is once I click the question1 or question2 button it inserting both of the ID's in my database.

Like this: [image]

Here's My Controller

```
    $data['posts'] = $this->Post_Model->get_posts();

    $this->load->view('templates/header');
    $this->load->view('posts/index', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');

    $this->load->library('form_validation');  

    if($this->form_validation->run()==FALSE) {  
        if($this->input->post("add")) {  
            $this->Post_Model->count_up();
            redirect('posts');
        }  

    }
```

My Model

```
function count_up(){
    for($i=0; $i<count($this->input->post('hidden')); $i++){
        $data = array(  
                'post_id' => $this->input->post("hidden[$i]")
            ); 

        $this->db->insert("userspost", $data);
    }
}
```

My View

```
<?php 
    $iq = 0;
    $i = 0;
    $arrtry = array();
    foreach($posts->result() as $post){ 
?>

    <br>
    <div class="card card-nav-tabs">
        <div class="card-header card-header-primary">
            <!-- colors: "header-primary", "header-info", "header-success", "header-warning", "header-danger" -->
            <div class="nav-tabs-navigation">
                <input class="form-control" value="<?php echo $arrtry[$iq++] =  $post->id;  ?>" name="hidden1[<?php $i; ?>]" type="hidden">

                <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="add" value="UP" />

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

<?php 
    $i++;               
    }  
?>
```

My problem is i want to insert question2 ID without inserting question1 ID. Hope you guys can help thanks!

Comment: You probably have the same form for both buttons, right?

Comment: yes `<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>posts/index">`

Comment: `<?php $i; ?>` isn't doing anything, and `<?php echo $arrtry[$iq++] =  $post->id;  ?>` doesn't belong there. If you need to do variable assignments, they should be done up top (or, even better, in the controller.)

Comment: <?php $i; ?>  I need this to differentiate the name of input

Answer (score 2):

What is happening is that you have all your inputs within the same form with multiple submit buttons.

I can imagine a few ways you could solve this:

- Ajax way. Require some JS and another controller method.
- One form for each button: So you will always have one `$this->input->post('hidden')`. No need to iterate over it.
- With only one form You could set the button for something like this:

`<input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="add-up" value="<?= $i; ?>" />`

So on your controller/model you can get the index that was clicked:

```php
/* controller/model */
$index = $this->input->post('add-up');
$hidden_value = $this->input->post("hidden")[$index]
```

Comment: i tried it but it said `post_id` was null my controller: `$index = $this->input->post("add")
               $hidden_value = $this->input->post("hidden")[$index];
                
                    $this->Post_Model->count_up($hidden_value);
                       redirect('posts'); 
` my model: ` function count_up($hidden_value){
            
                $data = array(  
                    'post_id' => $hidden_value
                );
            $this->db->insert("userup", $data);
        
        }`